# JSF messages for ui repeat input

Tags: validation, jsf-2, uirepeat

I have a JSF2 application that uses `<ui:repeat />` to render a number of text-boxes, each linked to an item in a collection. I need to show the error messages after the inputs in a single `<h:messages />` tag.

At the same time, I have some other required fields outside the `<ui:repeat />` tag, which 
should have its  error message next to their input, therefore they will have a corresponding `<h:message />` tag. The problem here is that each time I have triggered the outside field's validation, its message appears also in the `<h:messages />` tag of the `<ui:repeat />`.

Here is the code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><h:outputLabel value="Items"/></td>
        <td>
            <ui:repeat var="i" value="#{itemsBean.itemsCount}" id="items">
                <h:inputText id="itemTitle" value="#{itemsBean.items[i]}" required="true" />
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="clear" rendered="#{((i+1) % 10 == 0)}" />
            </ui:repeat>
            <h:messages id="itemsMessages" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" styleClass="error_list" />
        </td>
        <td><h:outputLabel value="Required Field" /></td>
        <td>
            <h:inputText id="requiredField" value="#{itemsBean.requiredField}" />
            <h:message for="requiredField" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" styleClass="error_list" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know that this is the way JSF validation works, but I need to prevent the outside input's message from appearing in the repeated items validation summary. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue?

Comment: @edhedges, I'm afraid not. I have used a workaround though, having the message moved outside the <ui:repeat /> and setting the messages server-side

Answer (score 0):

Try `<h:messages id="itemsMessages" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" styleClass="error_list" globalOnly="true"/>`

This causes the component to only show messages from message-components with no for-attribute set.

Comment: I tried it, but now the messages for the inputs in the `<ui:repeat />` do not appear.